# how to break flash builder application?

Tags: c#, debugging, flash-builder

I am working on the flash builder 4 application, which we are using for the UI of project. the business logic is developed in C#.

My question is "How can I debug my flash application? Currently I have put breakpoint in application, but while I run the application, not any breakpoint is faced, so I cant able to debug my application."

Please help me to solve this problem

Thank You

Comment: Are you using the debug version of Flash Player?

Comment: the flash application is integrate with the asp.net and start in the web browser.[I am new to flash technology, so could you explain me, ho w to know the flash player version and difference? Thank You for reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that you have breakpoints throughout your Flash application. This means that you have access to the source code, which is necessary for debugging.

If you're using the Flash Builder IDE, you can configure the debugger to run with an application embedded in a website. Here's how to do this:

1. Go to **Debug configurations** (the drop-down icon on the Debug button on the top menu)
2. In the "URL or path to launch" section of the opened window, uncheck "Use default" .
   Finally, enter your C# application's URL. (If you're running locally, it should be something like "localhost/myproject/index.aspx", or "[ASP server's IP]:[port]/index.aspx").

Now, if you press the debug button, Flash Builder will run your project, but also debug the .swf file.

Hope this helps. Have a great day.

Comment: You're welcome, please mark the answer as accepted, so other people who encounter this problem will know that this is the solution.